# Convert this cURL command with proxy to a Node.JS code

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, proxy

I have the following cURL command:

```
curl.exe -X GET -k _https://url --proxy proxy.example:80 --proxy-user "user:password"
```

I've been trying using a global proxy like global-tunnel or something like node-tunnel but I dont know if its a correct approach

The question is how to transform this curl command in a Node.js code

I guess that must be a simple solutions but I couldn't figure it out

Comment: What is your question here? Is it, whether using a Proxy is the correct approach? What your you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The question is how to transform this curl command into a Node.js code

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#proxies) library.

```
import request from 'request'
const params = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://url',
  proxy: 'http://user:password@proxy.example:80'
}
request(params, (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err
  // handle result...
})
```

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way the request library is now deprecated, check out axios instead. Its the recommended one right now and has a similar api.